# getting data from oracle database to postgresql in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, oracle, postgresql

I am making a microservice. To tell the truth I could not find satisfactory answer. More precisely, there is a big oracle database. In my microservice has PostgreSQL I want to bring only `first_name, last_name and phone number` data to PostgreSQL unfortunately there is no API for this. My Question is how can I import specific table data to PostgreSQL? If question is unclear please let me know!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is unclear. Why don't you directly connect to the Oracle database from your microservice?

Comment: @Selcuk because I should insert some data from my side

Comment: A program can connect to two databases at the same time.

Comment: The *import* of the data is only a minor problem. The tricky part is to *keep the data in sync* with the central database. Not to mention to push the changes back is you can modify the the data. In general you are right, IMO *there is no satisfactory concept for microservices accessing database data* (a dedicated database for each mircoservice doesn't work even in a powerpoint). Pragmatic solutions simple implement classical stored procedures on a central database and *call them miroservices*

Comment: Access Oracle's tables as [foreign](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw) tables in your Postgresql database

Comment: I agree with @LaurenzAlbe. You can define two data sources in your Django configuration and use your PostgreSQL table only for storing the extra information which is not in Oracle.